# postgresql procedure

Tags: postgresql, procedure

i am writing a folloing pgsql procedure :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION KNN(gid_ integer)
RETURNS Text AS $body$
DECLARE
row_ RECORD;
BEGIN
    SELECT  g1.gid As SOURCE, g2.gid As Neighbors  FROM polygons as g1, polygons as   g2  WHERE g1.gid = $1 and g1.gid <> g2.gid  ORDER BY g1.gid, 
ST_Distance(g1.the_geom,g2.the_geom) limit 5;
END
$body$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Now that the query return 5 rows for each value of arrgument supplied to procedure. How can i return those 5 rows. Also, how can i execute the procedure for all values of argument stored in a table polygons as column gid. Please somebody give the full code please. thankful to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `RETURNS TABLE` syntax to implicitly create `OUT` variables:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION KNN(
    gid_ integer
) RETURNS TABLE (
    source  integer,
    neighbor integer
) LANGUAGE SQL AS $$
    SELECT g1.gid As SOURCE
         , g2.gid As Neighbors
      FROM polygons AS g1,
           polygons AS g2
     WHERE g1.gid = $1
       AND g1.gid <> g2.gid
     ORDER BY g1.gid
         , ST_Distance(g1.the_geom,g2.the_geom)
     LIMIT 5;
$$;
```

To use it, use `SELECT * FROM KNN(42)` and you will get back up to five two-column rows.

Comment: ok, also , i have to execute this function for every value of column gid in table polygons. I guess i have to use cursor for that. How can i do that ? Ca you please do that also for me. Thanks for the help.

Comment: please help , how can i call the above function for the set of different argument values stored as gid column in table polygons.

Comment: I do not understand your questions.